# Usage of "topped by"

Tags: word-usage

> The sky was azure blue, topped by scudding white clouds.”

Is this sentence correct with the use of "topped"?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct and understandable although the description

> topped by scudding white clouds

is not normally found.

The picture being painted is a blue sky with very high clouds, however clouds have a maximum ceiling of around 20,000 feet, not very high considering commercial airlines routinely fly above that.